# Accessing instance variable

Tags: java, class, instance-variables

I have read from a website that instance variables can be accessed directly within the class but my code below works only with object. can someone please help.Thanks in advance!

```
public class InstanceVariable
    {
        int instVariable;
        // Instance variable are accessed through objects
        public static void main(String []args)
        {
            /* Local variables has no default value but Instance variables 
            can have default value */
    
            int a = 10;
            // Here local variables a cannot have access modifiers
            InstanceVariable obj = new InstanceVariable();
            System.out.println(obj.instVariable);
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You will have to define variable instVariable as static in order to access it without the help of object in the main method

Comment: Your question is one of the basic aspects of object oriented languages. If you struggle at this point, then I forsee you having lots of other similar questions in near future. Instead of asking here, I'd highly suggest you to grab a book about any object oriented language and go through it. It'll explain such core concepts much better than SO can.

Comment: This site is not for tutorials on the basics of Java. Study the extensive [*Java Tutorials*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) provided free of cost by Oracle. Read the new 2022 edition of [*Head First Java*](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-java/9781492091646/).